# FrameTicks and GridLines in DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

I would like to know what is the best way to configure one `GridLine` for the hour in `LightGray` and another for the days in `Gray`. In my tests, the `FrameTicks` are superposed by the GridLines and I don't know how to control the color. The data label should appear just for days.

Here is my attempt that I consider very clumsy.

```
data={#,RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0,1]]}&/@RandomReal[{3564979299,3565355902},1000];

DateListPlot[data
   ,AspectRatio->0.2
   ,DateTicksFormat->{"Day","/","Month"}
   ,GridLines->{{#,LightGray}&/@DateRange[{2012,12,12},{2012,12,31},"Hour"],None}
   ,FrameTicks->{Automatic,{DateRange[{2012,12,12},{2012,12,31},"Day"],None}}
   ,Epilog->{Gray,Line[{{#,Min@data[[All,2]]},{#,Max@data[[All,2]]}}]&/@AbsoluteTime/@DateRange[{2012,12,12},{2012,12,31},"Day"]}
]
```

[image]

I don't like to use `Epilog` for that. It would be nice if I could have subticks between the days ticks too, one subtick for each hour, with no label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get rid of the `Epilog` you can change the setting for `Gridlines` as follows:

```
data = {#, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]} & /@ 
  RandomReal[{3564979299, 3565355902}, 1000];


DateListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 0.2, 
DateTicksFormat -> {"Day", "/", "Month"},
GridLines -> {Join[{#, LightGray} & /@ 
 DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Hour"], {#, Gray} & /@
  DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Day"]], None},
FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Day"], None}}]
```

[image]

Update: Using @rm-rf's idea to change the color conditionally:

```
DateListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 0.2, 
DateTicksFormat -> {"Day", "/", "Month"},
GridLines -> {{#, If[Last@# === 0, Gray, LightGray]} & /@ 
   DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Hour"], None}, 
FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Day"], None}}]
```

Update 2: Further variations to  specify  both `Gridlines` and `FrameTicks`

```
 DateListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 0.2,
  GridLines -> {{#, {LightGray, Gray}[[2 - Sign[Last[#]]]]} & /@
    DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Hour"], None},
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {{{#, "",
     {.005, 0}, Directive[Red, Thick]},
    {#, DateString[#, {"Day", "/", "Month"}],
     {0.01, 0}, Directive[Blue, Thickness[.01]]}}[[2 - Sign[Last[#]]]] & /@
  DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Hour"], None}}]
```

[image]

Or

```
 DateListPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 0.2,
  GridLines -> {{#, {LightGray, Gray}[[2 - Sign[Last[#]]]]} & /@
      DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Hour"], None},
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {If[Last@# === 0,
   {#, DateString[#, {"Day", "/", "Month"}], {0.01, 0}, 
        Directive[Blue, Thickness[.01]]},
   {#, "", {.005, 0}, Directive[Red, Thick]}] & /@
   DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Hour"], None}}]
```

Comment: Very nice!.. I did't know I could use `Gridlines` like that. Tks! +1

Comment: is there a possibility to put GridLines in the foreground?

Comment: @Frink, use the `Method` option with the setting `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the fact that a valid `"Day"` using `DateRange` is already an element in the list returned using `"Hour"` (the last element is 0), you can use a simple replacement rule as follows for the `GridLines`:

```
GridLines -> {DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Hour"] /. 
    {d : {_, _, _, 0} :> {d, Gray}, h : {_, _, _, Except[0]} :> {h, LightGray}}, None}
```

An equivalent replacement rule using `If`:

```
x : {_, _, _, _} :> If[Last@x === 0, {x, Gray}, {x, LightGray}]
```

Comment: Cool.. there is another based in yours: `If[Last@# === 0, {#, Gray}, {#, LightGray}] & /@ 
 DateRange[{2012, 12, 12}, {2012, 12, 31}, "Hour"]`