# Drawing minor gridlines

Tags: plotting

What's the best (most elegant, shortest, easiest to read) way to add minor grid lines to a plot?

Here is an example:

```
data = Table[{x, Log@x}, {x, 100}];
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image: what I get]

But this gives gridlines only at the position of the  major frameticks. I'm looking for an easy way to automatically generate minor grid lines at the positions of minor frameticks (in a style different from the major gridlines).

Here is an example (yes, made in excel)

[image: What I would like to get]

I guess I could write half a page of code to generate both the frame ticks and the gridlines, but it seems like an overkill.

I realize this is very similar to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16975/frameticks-and-gridlines-in-datelistplot), but if I have to enter the ranges manually for each plot then I might as well draw my plots in excel.

Comment: Maybe could use similar methods in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2289/17).

Comment: Somewhat related: [(54613)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54613/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not elegant, but at least it's quite short :)

```
makeGrid[{minX_, maxX_}, {minY_, MaxY_}, {xStep_, yStep_}] := 
 {AbsoluteThickness[.25],
   Table[{If[Mod[x, 10] == 0, Black, LightGray], 
     Line[{{x , -100}, {x , 100}}]}, {x, minX, maxX, xStep}],
   Table[{If[Mod[y, 1] == 0, Black, LightGray], 
     Line[{{-100, y}, {100, y}}]}, {y, minY, MaxY, yStep}]}

ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
 Prolog -> makeGrid[{0, 100}, {0, 10}, {10, .1}]]
```

[image: rules]

Comment: +1 for `Prolog`. Had a [similar one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2329/17). :)

Comment: @Silvia so that's where I'd seen it before! :) Still, good practice to code these things up without looking sometimes...

Comment: Good practice indeed :)

Answer (score 14):

This is what came to my mind

```
myGridDivision[{min_, max_}, {major_, majorStyle_}, {minor_, minorStyle_}] :=
 Function[divisions,
   Join[{#, majorStyle} & /@ divisions[[1]],
    {#, minorStyle} & /@ Complement[Flatten[#[[2]]], #[[1]]] &@ divisions]
   ][FindDivisions[{min, max}, {major, minor}]]

ListPlot[data, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 5}},
 GridLines -> {
   myGridDivision[{0, 100}, {5, GrayLevel[.5]}, {5, GrayLevel[.8]}],
   myGridDivision[{0, 5}, {5, GrayLevel[.5]}, {5, GrayLevel[.8]}]
   }]
```

[image]

You can always set `min`/`max` to far more negative/positive large than the actual range of the plot to avoid manully determine the range.

Unfortunately, for some custom set `FrameTicks` cases, it seems not possible to auto-determine the `FrameTicks` setting using `AbsoluteOptions[(*graphics*), FrameTicks]` after the plot has been generated.. Maybe a home-made frame-ticks generator along with this one would be good.

Answer (score 8):

**Update 2:** If it is ok to have minor and major gridlines with the same style, then the simplest solution is to use `Full` as the option setting:

```
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {Full, Full}]
```

[image]

AFAIK, this setting is not documented.

**Update:** A more convenient approach is to use the function `` Charting`FindTicks ``:

```
ClearAll[gridLinesF2]
gridLinesF2[majorstyle_: Thick, minorstyle_: Thin] := Replace[
   DeleteDuplicatesBy[Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}][##][[All, ;; 2]], First], 
     {{a_, ""} :> {a, minorstyle}, {a_, b_} :> {a, majorstyle}}, 1] &

ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {gridLinesF2[Blue, Green], gridLinesF2[]}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

`GridLines` option setting can be a function. Using `FindDivisions` (as in Silvia's answer) without specific values for *min* and *max* (i.e., letting `FindDivisions` use automatically generated *min* and *max* values) and using `{6, 6}` as the second argument we get major and minor `GridLines` that match automatic ticks.

```
ClearAll[gridLinesF]
gridLinesF[style1_: Directive[Thickness[.003], GrayLevel[.5]], 
  style2_: Directive[Thin, GrayLevel[.9]], divs_:{6, 6}] := 
 Join[Thread[{#, style1}], 
   Thread[{DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates[Join @@ #2], Alternatives @@ #], style2}]] & @@
 FindDivisions[{##}, divs] &
```

**Examples:**

```
data = Table[{x, Log@x}, {x, 100}];
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {gridLinesF[], gridLinesF[]}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{RandomInteger[100], RandomReal[127]} + # & /@ data, 
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> {gridLinesF[], gridLinesF[]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[Circle[], Frame -> True, GridLines -> {gridLinesF[Red], gridLinesF[Blue]}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {gridLinesF[Directive[Thickness[.01], Red], Orange], 
   gridLinesF[Directive[Thickness[.01], Blue], Green]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think it is quite useful since it is automatically applicaple:

```
data = Table[{x, Log@x}, {x, 100}];
plot = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
{leftTicks, bottomTicks} = 
AbsoluteOptions[plot, FrameTicks][[ 1, 2, {2, 1}]];
```

we are taking `FrameTicks` from automatic plot, then we are taking labeled ticks as thicker `GridLines` and rest as thinner:

```
horizontalGridLines = 
leftTicks /. {x_?NumericQ, y_String, z__} :> {x, 
 GrayLevel@.9} /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z__} :> {x, Black}

verticalGridLines = 
bottomTicks /. {x_?NumericQ, y_String, z__} :> {x, 
 GrayLevel@.9} /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z__} :> {x, Black}

ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
GridLines -> {verticalGridLines, horizontalGridLines}]
```

Comment: `AbsoluteOptions[plot, FrameTicks]` won't work for some kinds of custom setting `FrameTicks`, say `FrameTicks -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}`.

Comment: So do not set it for first plot. It is only to get values we need. But I agree that exact values of `FrameTicks` given by user in final plot may not match those GridLines in general case.

Comment: Good call! (+1)

Comment: Fix for V11.1: Change `plot` and the line after to `plot = ListPlot[data, Frame -> False, GridLines -> Automatic]; {leftTicks, bottomTicks} = AbsoluteOptions[plot, Ticks][[1, 2, {2, 1}]];`.  Then the rest can stay, or replace the second `ListPlot` with `Show[plot, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {verticalGridLines, horizontalGridLines}]`.

Answer (score 2):

Using elements from Kuba's great answer this is what I came up with:

```
addMajorMinorGridLines[plot_, majorStyle_, minorStyle_] := 
 Block[{leftTicks, bottomTicks, horizontalGridLines, 
   verticalGridLines},
  {leftTicks, bottomTicks} = AbsoluteOptions[plot, FrameTicks][[1, 2, {2, 1}]];
  horizontalGridLines = 
   leftTicks /. {x_?NumericQ, y_String, z__} :> {x, minorStyle} 
            /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z__} :> {x, majorStyle};

  verticalGridLines = 
   bottomTicks /. {x_?NumericQ, y_String, z__} :> {x, minorStyle} 
               /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z__} :> {x, majorStyle};
  Show[plot, GridLines -> {verticalGridLines, horizontalGridLines}]
  ]


plot = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Red];
addMajorMinorGridLines[plot, Directive[Thick, Black], Directive[Thin, Opacity@0.3]]
```

[image]

Comment: How will you deal with plot with non-integer ticks, say `plot = ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{-1, 0, 1}, None}, {{0, Pi, 2 Pi, 3 Pi}, None}}]`?

Comment: I tried upvoting this but stackexchange temporarily [lost the plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wly1b.png)

Comment: @Silvia Good point. I guess "Not now" is not a good answer? I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: @Ajasja I would say re-constructing a `ListGridPlot` from `Graphics` and primitives. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You just need:

```
GridLines -> {Range[0, 100, 5], Range[0, 5, 0.2]}

data = Table[{x, Log @ x}, {x, 100}];

ListPlot[data,
  Frame -> True,
  GridLines -> {Range[0, 100, 5], Range[0, 5, 0.2]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 5}}]
```

Comment: The grid lines all have equal weight unlike the image in the OP