# How to get axes behind plot lines in ListLinePlot3D?

Tags: plotting

I have made this 3D figure:
[image]

I want the lines to be in front of the axes. Here is the code that I used:

```
data1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0.8, 0, 0}}
data2 = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0.5}}

plot = ListLinePlot3D[{data1, data2},
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
   PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
   Boxed -> False,
   ViewPoint -> {3, 2, 2},
   Ticks -> None,
   AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[.005]],
   PlotStyle -> {{Gray, Thickness[.05]}, {Red, Thickness[.05]}}
   ];
Show[plot, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]
```

As can be seen, I have used `Show` and `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` excerpt [from this previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/195325/22432) . Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.

How can this be achieved for all the lines in the plot?

Comment: [related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32168/125)

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32168/125), it seems it is impossible to occlude axes in `Graphics3D` unless they are placed on box edges using `AxesEdge`.

In your case, a simple work-around is to use graphics primitives instead of built-in axes:

```
axes = Graphics3D[{Thick, InfiniteLine[{0, 0, 0}, #] & /@ IdentityMatrix[3]}];

Show[axes, plot, Axes -> False,Options[plot]]
```

[image]

**Update:** A more flexible approach is to define a function that extracts relevant axes options from a plot object and creates a `Graphics3D` object with the desired line primitives:

```
axes3D = Graphics3D[Flatten @ Cases[{True | Automatic, a__} :> a] @
  Thread[{#, #2, (x |-> InfiniteLine[{#3, x}]) /@ 
        (IdentityMatrix[3] + Threaded[#3])}] & @@ 
  Values @ AbsoluteOptions[#, {Axes, AxesStyle, AxesOrigin}], 
  Boxed -> False] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Show[axes3D[plot], plot, Axes -> False, Options[plot]]
```

[image]

```
plot2 = ListLinePlot3D[{data1, data2}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, .5, -.25}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {3, 2, 2}, 
  Ticks -> None, 
  AxesStyle -> (Directive[#, Thickness[.005]] & /@ {Green, Blue, Orange}), 
  PlotStyle -> {{Gray, Thickness[.05]}, {Red, Thickness[.05]}}]
```

[image]

```
Show[axes3D[plot2], plot2, Axes -> False, Options[plot2]]
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `Ticks` is a huge challenge.

Comment: for a quick-and-dirty-custom-3dticks see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80452/125)