# Wiggly and imprecise animated gif output

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, animation

Trying to make animated gif of zooming into famous [Ford circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle). With the code

```
visibleQ[lh_, hr_, c_, k_] := Which[
  lh >= 1/(2 k), If[2 c k^2 <= 1 && lh^2 < c (1 - c k^2), True, False],
  hr >= 1/(2 k), If[2 c k^2 <= 1 && hr^2 < c (1 - c k^2), True, False],
  True, True]
t = {}
With[{center = 1/π, s = 1.04, start = 60},
 Module[{d = s^start},
  For[maxz = start, maxz < 300, maxz++; d *= s,
   With[{a = center - 2/3/d, b = center + 2/3/d, c = 2/3/d, e = -1/120/d},
    AppendTo[t,
     Graphics[
      {
       Line[{{-1, 0}, {2, 0}}],
       Table[
        Map[
         Circle[{#/k, 1/(2 k^2)}, 1/(2 k^2)] &,
         Select[Range[k], visibleQ[a k - #, # - b k, c, k] && CoprimeQ[#, k] &]
        ],
        {k, 12 Sqrt[3 d/2]}
       ]
      },
      ImageSize -> 500, PlotRange -> {{a, b}, {e, c}}
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
]
Export["..\\Desktop\\ford240.gif", t]
```

(which I adapted from [a Wolfram demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FordCircles/) and optimized a bit) I get this:
[image]

As you see the circles tremble unpleasantly, and occasionally intersect each other, although according to the formulæ they must always touch only.

How can this be improved?

Searching for similar questions I only found [How to avoid the wiggly text on Ticks and Labels when rotating 3D objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94470/35000) but that one is about text and I could not figure out whether it might be useful in any way here.

There is another problem too. It concerns mathematics rather than Mathematica, but still let me ask about it here. By monitoring `maxz` I found out that each next frame renders more slowly than the previous - which is of course understandable as it requires working with larger and larger ranges of `k`. But on the other hand the number of circles in each frame is roughly the same, so in principle there must be a way to program it so that every frame takes roughly the same amount of time. Can it be done?

**Update**

Using the suggestion by J. M. I switched to Farey sequences. This allowed to remove coprimeness check, but strangely enough became even slower. I don't know why but now rasterization takes more time.

```
visibleQ[a_, b_, c_, x_] := 
 With[{r = 1/(2 Denominator[x]^2)}, Which[
   x <= a - r, If[r c <= 1 && (a - x)^2 < c (2/r - c), True, False],
   x >= b + r, If[r c <= 1 && (x - b)^2 < c (2/r - c), True, False],
   True, True]
  ]
tocircle[x_] := With[{r = 1/(2 Denominator[x]^2)}, Circle[{x, r}, r]]
With[{center = 1/π, zoomstep = 1.04, start = 60, size = 504},
 Module[{d = zoomstep^start},
  For[count = start; t = {}, count < 300, count++; d *= zoomstep,
   With[{left = center - 2/3/d, right = center + 2/3/d, height = 2/3/d, bottom = -1/120/d},
    l = Select[FareySequence[Floor[Sqrt[3 size d]/2]], visibleQ[left, right, height, #] &];
    AppendTo[t,
     Rasterize[
      Graphics[
       {Line[{{-1, 0}, {2, 0}}], Map[tocircle, l]},
       ImageSize -> size, PlotRange -> {{left, right}, {bottom, height}}
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ]
  ]
 ]
]
```

And there is hardly any improvement on accuracy of the plot.

**Update 2**

Still could not figure out what's wrong with Farey sequences, so I abandoned them and improved instead the visibility check. It is now reasonably quick, reached 725 frames in less than an hour. So the second question seems to be settled, but the first one (about wiggling and crossings) remains.

[image]

Here is the new code - less readable I'm afraid.

```
frames = {};
With[{center = 1/π, zoomstep = 1.04, start = 60, size = 504},
 Module[{d = 3 zoomstep^start, maxden = 0, rats = {}, outrats, inrats, newrats, den},
  Do[
   With[{left = center - 2/d, right = center + 2/d, height = 2/d, bottom = -1/40/d},
    outrats = 
     Select[Select[rats, 2 Last[#]^2 height <= 1 &], 
      With[{oden = Last[#], pm = Sqrt[height (1 - Last[#]^2 height)]},
         left oden - pm < First[#] < right oden + pm] &];
    inrats = 
     Select[Select[rats, 2 Last[#]^2 height > 1 &], 
      With[{iden = Last[#], pm = 1/(2 Last[#])}, 
        left iden - pm < First[#] < right iden + pm] &];
    For[den = maxden + 1; newrats = {}, den^2 <= d size, den++,
     newrats = 
      Union[newrats, 
       Map[{#, den} &, 
        Select[Range[Ceiling[left den - 1/(2 den)], 
          Floor[right den + 1/(2 den)]], CoprimeQ[#, den] &]]]
     ];
    rats = Union[outrats, inrats, newrats];
    maxden = Max[Map[Last, rats]];
    d *= zoomstep;
    AppendTo[frames,
     Graphics[
      {
       Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
       Map[With[{r = 1/(2 Last[#]^2)}, Circle[{Divide @@ #, r}, r]] &, rats]
      },
      ImageSize -> size, PlotRange -> {{left, right}, {bottom, height}}
      ]
     ]
    ],
   900
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

**Update 3**

As requested by [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov) I've tried to isolate one simple case of the phenomenon. With wiggling I don't even realize how to proceed, however with circle crossings there is a very clear case: I've tried

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{Circle[{0, 1/2}, 1/2], Circle[{1/q, 1/(2 q^2)}, 1/(2 q^2)]}], 
  PlotRange -> {{1/q - 1/(2 q^2), 1/q + 1/(2 q^2)}, {0, 1/q^2}}
 ],
 {q, 1, 100, 1}
]
```

and discovered that already starting from q=4 the crossing is clearly visible. Here is a snapshot with q=21, together with a calculation showing that these circles must intersect in only one point

[image]

Comment: Since `FareySequence[]` is now built-in, I think the code can certainly be improved.

Comment: @J.M. Many thanks for pointing this out, but I seem to be using it in a wrong way (see update).

Comment: Could it be due to some anti-aliasing algorithm?

Comment: @Peltio In the documentation I only found something about dithering method but this must be something different...

Comment: I have checked some frames of your last animation in Paint and found that they are antialiased with artifacts (see for example at the bottom of [the third frame](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ibbn1.gif) - there are unwanted gray pixels inside of some of the free areas). Though I have not found any crossing, the quality of the antialiasing is rather poor. I recommend to switch off the antialiasing by wrapping with `Style[..., Antialiasing -> False]`. If you are unsatisfied with the result, I recommend to use custom antialiasing method (for example, based on `ImageResize`).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Sorry I should indicate that in the question, the second gif (as opposed to the first) is postprocessed at ezgif.com to reduce size, it was above 4mb. Still many thanks for the information, I will try to switch out antialiasing. Also maybe shrinking a large image will give better results, will try this too and report here.

Comment: As for crossings, they are especially bad in frames with one circle with radius much larger than the rest. And in these cases it seems to be related to numeric precision rather than graphics, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, this may be a numerical precision issue. Please reduce your code to a minimum, which would demonstrate the problem. Actually it is very difficult to work with your current examples which take a lot of processor time and too large. I suggest you to prepare minimal examples on every issue you face.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I've added an illustration of a simple case of crossing. With wiggling, I don't quite know how to pin down simple cases.

Comment: (In fact when I abort evaluation after a minute or so, there are already enough frames so that wiggling is clearly visible (or you can just change the second argument of `Do` to a smaller value))

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9560/unexpected-behavior-of-geometrictransformation/

Comment: @J.M. After some [clarifications](http://mathoverflow.net/q/224816/41291) at [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/224913/41291) I think I understand better what's happening. Working with the whole new Farey sequence is not advantageous as its length grows; what has to be implemented to have really nice speed is to take the previously found fragment of a Farey sequence, saturate it with new fractions up to new zoom resolution and throw out those with circles grown out of the picture.

Comment: There is one problem however - it seems not to be true that the set of circles visible in the picture always corresponds to a contiguous succession of elements in a Farey sequence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try calculating your own circles. (This puts the computation in the CPU with 64-bit floats instead of, I assume, in the GPU with 16/24/32-bit floats, depending on the processor and implementation.) The minimum number of circle points (`12` below) might need adjusting to the clarity & resolution of the display device.

```
circle[pt_, r_, scale_] := 
  Line@ Append[#, First[#]] &@ CirclePoints[N@pt, N@r, Ceiling[Max[12, 60*2 Pi r/scale]]];
```

Or pre-V10.1:

```
circle[pt_, r_, scale_] := 
  With[{npts = Ceiling[Max[12, 2 Pi r/scale]]}, 
   Line@ Transpose[
     pt + r Through[{Cos, Sin}[Rescale[N@Range[npts], {1, npts}, {0., 2. Pi}]]]]
   ];
```

Then replace `Circle[..] &` with

```
circle[{#/k, 1/(2 k^2)}, 1/(2 k^2), Abs[c - e]] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks quite promising and I tried but could not figure out what are `c` and `e`. I tried `r/height` (radius by size of the viewed rectangle) instead of your `Abs[c-e]`, the cycle is almost as quick, but exporting seems to take too much time (it is still not finished). So I don't know what is the optimal scale, could you please explain?

Comment: Oh I think i've got it, you mean `c` and `e` from my first code? The height itself?

Comment: Heigth definitely produces nice output, and is reasonably quick, but eats memory, at least in my case (4gb ram). After 500th frame it was swapping so wildly I could not even restart the system, had to switch the machine off by hand. Somehow I cannot figure out, is your scale designed in such way that one pixel radius requires one point only?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Yes `c` and `e` are from the first program.  I used the height; one could use width.  One can guess what to multiply by (`60*2 Pi` in my code), or one could calculate.  What looks good will depend on resolution of final images.  This might look good and use less memory: `Ceiling[Max[3, 15 2 Pi Sqrt[r/scale]]]`.

Comment: (1) Converting each frame to a bitmap can save some memory at the expense of vector graphics.  E.g. `ColorConvert[Rasterize[frames[[1]], "Image", ImageSize -> 500], "Grayscale"]` takes about 125KB. (2) Another idea is to compute every 10th frame or so and zoom in via changing the `PlotRange` (via something like  `Show[frame[[Ceiling[i/10]]], PlotRange -> {..}]`) on a given frame 10 times before moving to the next frame.

Comment: (1) seems to work - reached 500 frames without problems and now trying more. As for (2), it depends on how often new circles grow perceptibly, if I am not mistaken this happens more frequently than once in 10 frames and then the animation would become jumpy. Will try though, maybe it will work.