# How to increase length of minor and major ticks of a frame?

Tags: graphics, ticks, frame

Following is the mathematica command I am using to obtain a contour plot(attached). I see that the length of minor and major ticks are very small. What is a good command to increase the length of both ticks?.

```
Table[ContourPlot[
  f[\[ScriptCapitalD], {x, y}], {x, 55, 80}, {y, 15, 25}, 
  PlotRange -> Full,  
  PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 32, Black}], 
  ContourStyle -> Thickness[0.004],  ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
  Axes -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["x (m)", 32], Style["y (m)", 32]},  
  Contours -> 10, LabelStyle -> Black, FrameStyle -> Thickness[.005], 
  AxesStyle -> Black, ContourStyle -> Black, ContourShading -> None, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 12], 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 21}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/2.5 ], {f, {PDF, CDF}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you look help for [`FrameTicks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html). There is an example under *Generalization and Extensions* `fticks[min_, max_] := 
 Table[If[EvenQ[i], {i, i, {.1, 0}, Red}, {i, i, {.05, 0}, Blue}], {i,
    Ceiling[min], Floor[max], 1}]`

Comment: It appears that help does not cover this. You can look help for [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html?q=Ticks). It is essentially the same function.

Answer (score 4):

Though not clearly written in MMA help, `FrameTicks` accept function in a similar way as `Ticks` do. Hence the following code can be tweaked to do the job.

```
ClearAll[fticks]
fticks[min_, max_]:=Module[{division = Subdivide[min, max, 10]}, Table[If[EvenQ[i], {(*pos*)division[[i]], (*lbl*)i,(*size*) {.1, 0},(*col*)Red}, {(*pos*)division[[i]],(*lbl*)i,(*size*){.05, 0},(*col*) Blue}], {i, Range@Length@division}]]
Plot[Sin[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> fticks]
```

which gives

[image]

You can tweak the code to get what you want. Read help documentation for [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html?q=Ticks) to see more use cases.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2:** As noted by @ercegovac in a comment, using @Carl's fix in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68937/more-ticksticks-errors-in-absoluteoptions-in-v10), the approach in my original answer below also works in Version 11:

```
Show[cp, FrameTicks -> fticks]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using a modification of the function `tickF` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47039/125) to create a custom ticks function:

```
ClearAll[tickF];
tickF[s_ : 1][div1_, div2_ : -1] := (If[div2 == -1, 
    Thread[{#, #, s {.02, 0}}, List, 2] &@ FindDivisions[{#1, #2}, div1], 
    Join @@ MapAt[Join @@ # &, {Thread[{#, #, s {.02, 0}}, List, 2] &@#[[1]], 
      Thread[{#, "", s {.01, 0}}, List, 2] & /@ #[[2]]} &@
       FindDivisions[{#1, #2}, {div1, div2}], {2}]]) &
```

Example:

```
ft = (tickF[3][8, 5][## & @@ #] & /@ PlotRange[cp]);
Show[cp, FrameTicks -> {{ft[[2]], ft[[2]]}, {ft[[1]], ft[[1]]}}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

The following approach works in version 9:

```
cp = ContourPlot[Evaluate[Re[Product[x + I y - (a + I b), {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}]]],
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> 400];
```

Get the `FrameTicks` using `AbsoluteOptions` and post-process to increase the tick lengths:

```
fticks = FrameTicks /. AbsoluteOptions[cp, FrameTicks]; 
fticks[[All, All, 3]] = 5 fticks[[All, All, 3]];
```

Use `fticks` as the option value for `FrameTicks` in `Show`:

```
cp2 = Show[cp, ImageSize -> 400, FrameTicks -> fticks];
Row[{cp, cp2}]
```

[image]

Comment: I was curious about your approach. However, it throws error when tried to executed on my machine. See this [link](https://imgur.com/a/pvyL2).

Comment: @ercegovac, I cannot open the link. Please check if  the updated version I just posted gives the same error.

Comment: It throws error `{Automatic,Automatic} is not a valid tick specification`. Seams that graphics directive contains `FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}`. Possibly looking furhter into `Theme` for resolution. I have `"11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)"`

Comment: @ercegovac, it looks like `AbsoluteOptions`  doesn't work in version 11 (it does in version 9). I will post an alternative approach if/when I can think of one:)

Comment: It appears that, with introduction of `Themes`, the way MMA handles plotting changed. Now, default styles are found under `PlotThemes`. There is quite some discussion on that topic. I do not know who of the users is from Wolfram on this forum, but they should add in the help for `FrameTicks` that it can accept function in the same way as `Ticks`. Currently one has to go under *Generalization and Extensions* to see the usecase example.

Comment: Look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51846/specifying-non-conflicting-plottheme-options/87282#87282) thread, there is Mr.Wizard's follow up on your post. This prompted me that `Themes` introduced with v10 might be problem.

Comment: According to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68937/more-ticksticks-errors-in-absoluteoptions-in-v10) thread, it appears that there is a bug related to the use of `AbsoluteOptions` and `FrameTicks`,

Comment: Thank you @ercegovac. With Carl's fix, the approach in my original answer works in V11 as well.